# How to send standard input to background job?

Tags: command-line, scripts, ssh, wmctrl

After several trial & error, I installed another image viewer on my remote machine (`feh`), setting in up— and tried the command once again.

```
feh WARNING: /tmp/feh_stdin_ZwCjv7 - No Imlib2 loader for that file format
feh: No loadable images specified.
See 'man feh' for detailed usage information
```

I think this is the problem that caused ImageMagick's `display` to burst out error.

```
display: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
```

According to https://superuser.com/a/1517417/1106777, the command failed because  I started `display` as a background job (`&`).

> If the process is started with `&` then the shell will actually redirect its stdin from `/dev/null` to avoid any read attempts.

If I removed the trailing `&`, the command will ran without any problem, take an example of:

Working

```
ssh beer@laika "DISPLAY=:0 feh -" < <(cat 1.jpeg)
```

(Also) working

```
ssh beer@laika "DISPLAY=:0 display -" < <(cat 1.jpeg)
```

How to send stdin to background `&` job ?

Answer (score 2):

The command

```
display - && sleep 5 && wmctrl -r ImageMagick -e 0,254,600,800,560
```

starts the `display` command, **waits for it to exit**, and then runs `sleep 5 && wmctrl -r ImageMagick -e 0,254,600,800,560` if the exit status indicates success.

You probably want

```
display - & sleep 5 && wmctrl -r ImageMagick -e 0,254,600,800,560
```

which starts `display` in the shell background then immediately continues with the remaining commands.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work as it return `display: no decode delegate for this image format ' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.`.  I tried feh (another image viewer program), the error is `feh: No loadable images specified.`

Comment: It seems the image doesn't load properly if there's an extra command, what could be the cause ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be [authority issue over ssh](https://superuser.com/a/190878/662962):

> ### DISPLAY and AUTHORITY
>
> An X program needs two pieces of information in order to connect to an
>   X display. (Note that `wmctrl` is an X program, even if it accesses
>   other processes' windows rather than creating its own.)
>
> - It needs the address of the display, which is typically `:0` when you're logged in locally or `:10`, `:11`, etc. when you're logged in
>     remotely (but the number can change depending on how many X
>     connections are active). The address of the display is normally
>     indicated in the DISPLAY environment variable.
> - It needs the password for the display. X display passwords are called magic cookies. Magic cookies are not specified directly: they
>     are always stored in X authority files, which are a collection of
>     records of the form “display :42 has cookie 123456”. The X authority
>     file is normally indicated in the XAUTHORITY environment variable. If
>     `$XAUTHORITY` is not set, programs use `~/.Xauthority`.

Luckily you can solve this by setting up some cookies:

> To copy cookies when you log into your desktop X session, add the
>   following lines to `~/.xprofile` or `~/.profile` (or some other script
>   that is read when you log in):
>
> ```
> case :$DISPLAY:$XAUTHORITY in
>   :*:?*) XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority xauth merge "$XAUTHORITY";;
> esac
> ```

This is a small summary of the answer. Please visit the link above for all details.

Comment: Thanks, but I am aware of this issue and had already solved it— what I'm asking is sending stdin to `&` job, [user1686's superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1517417/1106777) said this is possible to do it within the shell itself.